# Bootstrap class in markdown table revealjs

Tags: markdown, quarto, reveal.js

I would like to use a striped markdown table like [here](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/tables.html) in my `reveal.js` presentation which is a bootstrap class. It seems to work for HTML output but not for reveal.js. Here is some reproducible code:

```
--- 
format: revealjs
---

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Fruit prices {.striped .hover}
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output looks like this:

[image]

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add bootstrap classes to a markdown table in a `reveal.js` presentation in `Quarto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In revealjs format, Bootstrap styles are not shipped automatically, unlike html format. So to use Bootstrap classes, you need to load the bootstrap styles manually. And then use the [bootstrap classes for tables i.e. `.table`, `.table-striped`, `.table-hover`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#striped-rows).

```
--- 
format: revealjs
tbl-cap-location: bottom
include-in-header: 
  text: |
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
---

<style>
caption {
  text-align: center !important;
}
</style>

| fruit  | price  |
|--------|--------|
| apple  | 2.05   |
| pear   | 1.37   |
| orange | 3.09   |

: Fruit prices {.table .table-striped .table-hover}
```

Also, you may need to change some CSS styles additionally, for example, the alignment of caption text to get similar tables as in the case of html format.

---

[image: bootstrap styled table in revealjs slide]